# IFC objects navigation to retrieve Wall coordinates

Tags: ifc

Has anyone already used the IFC (Industry Foundation Classes) from BuildingSmart, typically adopted for BIM projects and building domain ?
I would like to know how to navigate the IFC objects to get the coordinates of a IfcWallStandardCase or of an affine object (i.e., yet a Wall).

I am interesting in getting the coordinates of all or at least one of the vertices delimiting the Wall.
Please indicate the navigation through the Ifc objects of an Ifc file, to know where to locate the coordinates information in the Ifc file starting from an IfcWallStandardCase or affine object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First go for the `Representation` attribute which is optional for `IfcProduct`. You want shape representations (`IfcProductDefinitionShape`), not material representations. If there are representations at all, you may get multiple representations, each with a context specifying dimensionality, precision, and coordinate system. Since you are hunting for coordinates, you probably want a representation of type `IfcShapeRepresentation`, not `IfcTopologyRepresentation`. Each representation then consists of multiple representation items.

There are several types of geometry representations - check the inheritance tree of `IfcGeometricRepresentationItem`. Here is an example for a faceted BREP: each representation item is then of type `IfcFacetedBrep`, which is [explained nicely](http://www.buildingsmart-tech.org/ifc/IFC4/final/html/schema/ifcgeometricmodelresource/lexical/ifcfacetedbrep.htm) in the IFC2x4 specs. With attribute `outer` you get a closed shell, which consist of a set of faces (`IfcFace`) reachable trough the attribute `CfsFaces`. Each face has a set of bounds (`IfcFaceBound`, attribute `Bounds`), each of which is defined by a loop (`IfcLoop`, attribute `Bound`) and an orientation. The loops again may be of different type, let's assume `IfcPolyLoop`. Those have a list of points (`IfcCartesianPoint`) under the attribute `Polygon`, which finally give you the coordinates (of type `IfcLengthMeasure` which is a `REAL`) with attribute `Coordinates`.

Be aware that those coordinates are relative to the coordinate system of the geometric context mentioned in the beginning. Contexts may be nested with multiple coordinate transformations to be resolved in order to get absolute world coordinates.

The path of attribute names is: `Representation`, `Items`, `CfsFaces`, `Bounds`, `Bound`, `Polygon`, `Coordinates`.